# Can't connect to friends on Minecraft Windows 10 15.0 through Xbox

Tags: windows-10, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to play on my friend's world on Xbox from Minecraft Windows 10 Edition 15.0 and I get stuck on locating a server, then it says I can't connect. But my friends can join me. I don't want to be the host all the time when we play. I have the latest version of Windows 10 and I keep all my apps updated. I don't know why this is happening and I wanna know of any fixes.

Comment: What's wrong with being the host? Can your computer not handle it?

Comment: So it is cross comatable though?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because Microsoft only allows computers to host cross device servers.

Comment: Cannot be the case; I have played on a world hosted on my Xbox.